# Issues with the insert function to my database program

Tags: c#

Good day all! I'm having a minor issue with the insert to my program. See, the code has no errors but I'm having an OleDb exception when trying to insert. The other parts of my project work fine but there is a tiny issue here that I can't seem to find

```
 public void Insert()
    {
        //myDb = new OleDbConnection(conn + dbFile);
        myDb.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Employee", myDb);
        //
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Employee(Username, Password, email, phone) VALUES ('" + insUn + "','" + insPass + "','" + insNm + "','" + insNmr + "')", myDb);

        adapter.InsertCommand = cmd;

        adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();



        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds, "Employee");

        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "Employee";

        myDb.Close();
    }
```

The other functions such as the search and delete work but I can't find the problem here

These are the exceptions:

```
 try
        {
            if (textBox2.Text != "")
            {
                insUn = textBox2.Text;
                insNmr = textBox4.Text;
                insPass = textBox3.Text;
                insNm = textBox5.Text;
            }
            Insert();
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error, please try again", "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("One or more fields have not been entered. Please check and re-enter", "Missing fields", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
        }



enter code here
```

Comment: What oledb exception do you see?  Also, are you aware of [sql injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)?

Comment: I'm not really aware of sql injection though

Comment: you're catching exceptions, but not looking at the details of the exception.  You need to look at the stacktrace and/or the message the exception is returning

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use the `Parameter` to avoid SQL injections , and put the brackets `[]` in query for `[Password]` because it's a keyword like below :

```
 public void Insert()
 {
     //myDb = new OleDbConnection(conn + dbFile);
     myDb.Open();

     OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Employee(Username, [Password], email, phone) VALUES (@Username, @Password, @email, @phone)", myDb);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", insUn);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", insPass);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", insNm);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", insNmr);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

     OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Employee", myDb);
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     adapter.Fill(ds, "Employee");

     dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
     dataGridView1.DataMember = "Employee";

     myDb.Close();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! Let me try it out now

Comment: Please, remove a block try catch and try it for get the line how is error ?

Comment: error say tht object connection not closed, can you add `myDb.Close();` before line `myDb.Open();`

Comment: Just tried it. The exception now says a syntax error

Comment: The myDb.Close() line when I set it above the open

Comment: I advice you to use the Parameter to avoid SQL injections , like answer, and put the bracket[] in query for `[Password]` because it's a keyword in `MSAccess`

Comment: Alright thanks! I've tried it and I still get the errors. Sorry if this is becoming to much of an issue

Comment: what is the type of fields in DataBase ?

Comment: is all the textBox have data when you execute the code ?

Comment: Yes it does. I've made exception catches to catch missing information in the textboxes

Comment: I got it to work! Thanks for the help! Much appreciated!

Comment: Good! I'am glad to hear that

Answer (score 0):

Abdellah's answer will work, but be aware for SQL Injection attacks when building your query string. You should build it like this:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Employee(Username, Password, email, phone) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4)", myDb);
int maxSize = 50;
cmd.Paramters.Add("@p1", SqlDbType.VarChar, maxSize).Value = insUn;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", SqlDbType.VarChar, maxSize).Value = insPass;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p3", SqlDbType.VarChar, maxSize).Value = insNm;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p4", SqlDbType.VarChar, maxSize).Value = insNmr;
```